# npm "bin" scripts executing on import

Tags: typescript, npm

I have a TypeScript 4.8.4 library that's being packaged with npm. In my `package.json` I have a `"bin"` section that includes some utility scripts that are helpful for consumers of the package.

```json
  "bin": {
    "generate-docs": "./docs/docs.py",
    "configure-this-and-that": "lib/configure-this-and-that.js",
    "register-things": "lib/data/register-things.js"
  }
```

The trouble is that even the simplest usage triggers all those scripts to execute when this package is imported. *This happened when I updated to TypeScript 4.8*. Previously this wasn't happening with TS 3.7.

```
import { Anything } from 'my-package-from-above';

// This causes the files in "bin" above to run
const anything = new Anything();
console.log('Done');
```

Is this different behavior in TS4? Is it something with the package.json setup?

**Edit**
The class that's getting executed when imported looks like this. Is there something in the way it's written that could be doing it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
import { DeployUtility } from './deploy-utility';
const deployUtility = new DeployUtility();
deployUtility.configureDomainMapping().then(data => {
  return data;
});
```

The body of this class is getting executed whenever anything imports the containing package (even if it's not importing this class above).

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the rest of your project, but that's definitely not typical or expected behavior. Are you sure that nothing within the chain of dependencies of `Anything` imports/requires those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what the issue was, the scripts were being included in the index.ts file. Including the *.ts files that are used to generate the *.js files in the "bin" section of the package.json in the index.ts exports causes those files to be executed *anytime* the package is referenced.

The solution was to remove the exports that had a construct like the configureDomainMapping example above

Remove this (and any like it) from `index.ts`

```
export * from './configure-domain';
```